# observer for MongoDB changes in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I am using NodeJS with database MongoDB

In `node1` project when any docoument changes in the collections of that database.So their is another application( `node2` ) of nodeJS which i want to just observe that Database( in which changes are occured ). So that i want to Do something in `node2` project when in perticular collection changes has been done.

Thing I get:

**oplog** (operation log) *which helps to updateOrCreate other Replicas of mongodb Nodes* .

My ques is -:

1. What is the right approch to do this kind of thing ?
2. Can I use Socket.io for this approch ?

Any help would be appriciated .

Thanks

Comment: Have look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-observer and https://github.com/Automattic/mydb-observer and more module

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use micro-service architecture with nodeJs. Using messaging system would be easy to maintain, Any change would be published to appropriate service and would be handled easily. You can use RabbitMQ or Kafka for the purpose